# Sort HTML Table by Column on Load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, telerik

My page has a table (a telerik grid?) that, upon loading, I would like to sort by column, as if the one in question had been clicked by the user. I'm presuming the best way to do something like this is with telerik, javascript, or jquery, all of which I have a woeful lack of experience with, and I find myself not knowing just where to begin.

My thoughts are that the column in question will be selected by its text contents, as the only other identifier - class - is identical among them all. Then either trigger or replicate the column's onclick event. Am I going in the right direction with this? Would anyone have a suggested route to progress forward with this? I'm trying to treat this as more of a learning experience than just "give me answers!" sort of thing, which I hope is an acceptable thing to post around here.

EDIT: Besides the suggestion from @josh, below, I'm also experimenting with something like this.

```
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery("a:contains('submitted')").click();
});
</script>
```

or this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a:contains('submitted')").trigger('click'); 
});
```

Comment: I'm not a telerik user, but I'd start there before trying to explore client-side solutions. The documentation has info on setting an initial sort order: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/sorting/sort-expressions#declarative-sort-expressions

Comment: Hey, that may be exactly what I'm looking for! Their help is usually so dense that, as an unfamiliar user, I'm overwhelmed. Thank you so much!

Comment: You haven't said which Telerik grid you are using. There are several, depending on the platform. I believe that all of them have sorting capability built into the grid. Your proposed route of generating a click on the column header would probably work, but is just about the biggest hack you could do to get it to work. If you're not going to sort using the Telerik API, you could sort the dataset using SQL first, then load that into the grid.

Comment: I thought it felt a bit hacky. Appreciate the confirmation. :)